# Where can I find the default razor editor templates for dropdownlistfor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, open-source

I want to create a custom control (partial view, template) and have it function similar to html.dropdownlistfor() where it takes a collection to select from and another field to hold the selected value.  In order to do this, I want to review the code for dropdownlistfor.  Since ASP.NET MVC is open source, where can I find the code/razor markup to dropdownlistfor?

Comment: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#338505

Comment: I don't see DropDownListFor in there.  I am trying to figure out how DropDownListFor relates to DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [DropDownList source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#338505)
- [DropDownList extenstions](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#288014)
- [DropDownListFor extenstons](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#338518)

Comment: The unaccept was a mistake.  I was on my iPhone and must have pressed it again by mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

DropdownListFor does not use a template.  It's just an select tag with options.  DropDownListFor and DropDownList are the same, other than DropDownListFor uses a strongly typed lambda expression.  They both generate the same html.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the `SelectExtensions` in MVC source.

SelectExtensions.cs

If you're asking for the source code, you can get that at codeplex, [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781).

Comment: I don't see DropDownListFor in there.  I am trying to figure out how DropDownListFor relates to DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need " another field to hold the selected value. "?

```
  List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });
```

As you can see, the SelectListItem  has a Selected field. I have a pending DDL tutorial I can send you. It has a sample where you use a text input next to the DDL to add a new category for the DDL. This is implemented in jQuery. The code is at [Using the DropDownList and ListBox with ASP.NET MVC](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-the-DropDownList-67f9367d)  shoot me an email and I'll send you the tutorial.
ricka.anderson[at]microsoft.com